# Weierstrass M-Test

Tags: math-history

What does "M" stand for in Weierstrass M-Test?

Just asking...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The M stands for majorant.

In german it is also called [Weierstraßsches Majorantenkriterium](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstra%C3%9Fsches_Majorantenkriterium).

Comment: @boj54: You are welcome. You have asked 3 questions so far and all of them have been answered. You might want to consider accepting the answers to your questions.

Comment: sorry... I was not aware that i have to do it...

Comment: @boj54: No problem!